# Using piped output as filename in cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I want to uses pipes to redirect the output of one program to another like:

`type file.txt file2.txt | sort | someprog`

Now I've the problem that `someprog` isn't able to use the piped STDOUT and wants a file parameter:

`someprog somefile.txt`

How can I tell `someprog` to use the piped STDOUT? In bash (Linux) I would use a command like `someprog -` but this does not seems to work within the cmd.

Creating a temporary file for this unfortunately isn't an option for me.

Comment: some commands support this pattern, but it's not universal convention (and 'modifier' may be different). Does your file.txt contains sole parameter, or list of params (per line)?

Comment: "Creating a temporary file for this unfortunately isn't an option for me." - please explain why not? An intermediate temp file would be a good solution and can be automatically deleted afterwards ... all in the same command line ...

Comment: Can't understand yours _temporary file isn't an option for me_. I'd use `type file.txt file2.txt 2>NUL | sort > "%tmp%\somefile.txt"`

Comment: @wmz The files (file.txt file2.txt) I'm using are logfiles, which I'm sorting and want to parse within `someprog`.

@DavidPostill and @JosefZ The problem is it has really to be an absolut unique file, as this command can be called from another program multiple time and anytime and random numbers aren't truely random.

Comment: Then make up your temporary file name to be _unique_, combining (and/or) next items: `%random%`, `%date%`, `%time%` and `PID` of calling process...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A procedure `:unique` returns a temporary file name from momentary date and time. The precision of time is approximately 3 milliseconds, collision probability very close to zero.

```
@echo off
set "somefile="

call :unique somefile
rem echo %somefile%

type file.txt file2.txt 2>NUL | sort > "%tmp%\%somefile%.txt"
someprog "%tmp%\%somefile%.txt"
erase "%tmp%\%somefile%.txt"
goto :eof

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:unique
@SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
  set "unq="
  for /F %%G in ('WMIC OS GET localdatetime^|findstr /I /V "local"') do (
    set "unq=%%G")
  set "unq=%unq:.=%"
  set "unq=%unq:+=%"
@ENDLOCAL &set "%1=%unq%"
exit /B
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Comment: This seems like an solution that will work for me, as I've some additional data, which will make the file truely unique, thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

Reference [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

> `commandA &  commandB`      Run commandA and then run commandB
>
> `commandA && commandB`      Run commandA, if it succeeds then run commandB

Try the following:

```
type file.txt file2.txt | sort > mytempfile && someprog mytempfile && del mytempfile
```